# Show That $\dim H_m(\partial M;\mathbb{R})$ is Even

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

A student asked me this.  Suppose that $M$ is a compact, orientable $n$-manifold with boundary.  It is a fact that for each $k$ with $0\leq k\leq n$ the vector spaces $H_k(M;\mathbb{R})$ and $H_{n-k}(M,\partial M;\mathbb{R})$ are isomorphic.  Moreover, an isomorphism may be chosen between then such that in the diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
H_k(M;\mathbb{R}) @>{i}>> H_k(M,\partial M;\mathbb{R});\\
@V{\simeq}VV @V{\simeq}VV\\
H_{n-k}(M,\partial M;\mathbb{R}) @<{j}<< H_{n-k}(M;\mathbb{R});
\end{CD}
$$
the inclusion induced maps $i$ and $j$ have matrix representatives that are transposes of each other.  Now suppose that $\dim(M)=2m+1$.  Prove that $\dim H_m(\partial M;\mathbb{R})$ is even, and that the map $H_m(\partial M;\mathbb{R})\rightarrow H_m(M;\mathbb{R})$ has rank equal to $\frac{1}{2}\dim H_m(\partial M;\mathbb{R})$.

I'm not sure what to do here.  It seems if you let $n=2m+1$ and $k=m$ then $i$ must be injective due to the diagram.  But, then $H_m(\partial M;\mathbb{R})\rightarrow H_m(M;\mathbb{R})$ would be the zero map by the sequence of the pair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this part of the long exact sequence for $\partial M\subset M$:
$$H_{m+1}(M,\partial M;\mathbb R)\xrightarrow{a} H_m(\partial M;\mathbb R)\xrightarrow{b} H_m(M;\mathbb R).$$
This sequence is isomorphic to its dual 
$$H_m(M;\mathbb R)^*\xrightarrow{b^t} H_m(\partial M;\mathbb R)^*\xrightarrow{a^t} H_{m+1}(M,\partial M;\mathbb R)^*$$
(dual spaces, transposed maps) via Poincaré duality in each term (the isomorphism works for the entire long exact sequence, but we only need this part). Hence the kernel of $b$ is equal to the image of $a$, which is isomorphic to the image of $b^t$, which is equal to $(H_m(\partial M;\mathbb R)/(\ker b))^*$. As $\ker b\cong (H_m(\partial M;\mathbb R)/(\ker b))^*$, we get $\dim H_m(\partial M;\mathbb R)=2\dim\ker b$, as you wanted.

Notice though that I used more machinery than I see from your diagram, namely some properties of $a$ and $b$. So I don't know whether you'll find this answer satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

I have thought of a solution that does not require any more than what is given, unlike the previous solution. So, I thought I should post it. For $n = 2m + 1$ and $k = m$, We have the exact sequence:
$$
H_{m + 1}(M) \overset{j}{\to} H_{m + 1}(M, \partial M) \overset{\alpha}{\to} H_m(\partial M) \overset{\beta}{\to} H_m(M) \overset{i}{\to} H_m(M, \partial M).
$$
By exactness, and since the transpose of $i$ is $j$, we have that:
$$
\operatorname{Im}(\beta) = \ker(i) \cong \operatorname{coker}(j).
$$
Then by exactness:
$$
\operatorname{coker}(j) = \frac{H_{m + 1}(M, \partial M)}{\operatorname{Im}(j)} = \frac{H_{m + 1}(M, \partial M)}{\ker(\alpha)}.
$$
By isomorphism theorems, we have:
$$
\frac{H_{m + 1}(M, \partial M)}{\ker(\alpha)} \cong \operatorname{Im}(\alpha).
$$
But, $\operatorname{Im}(\alpha) = \ker(\beta)$.  Then $\operatorname{Im}(\beta) \cong \ker(\beta)$ and $H_m(\partial M) \cong \operatorname{Im}(\beta) \oplus \ker(\beta)$ give the results.